# 2 year diploma enough to start a career?

Tags: education

I'm finishing my degree in Art History soon and I'm realizing I am not as interested in my major than I originally thought I was. The idea of going to graduate school or working in an art history related field makes me feel really hopeless because I do not see myself working in such an industry.

I loved graphic design in high school and I've missed it all through my time at uni. I've chosen to carry on to a career in design (graphic or maybe even interior) but I do not feel like I have the time for another four-year degree. That, and I don't think I could handle another 4 years of university.

Will a diploma in graphic design suffice for a future career in the industry? What was it like entering the industry as someone with a diploma? I'm excited about beginning my new career path but also really nervous! Advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I go back to school for graphic design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/105791/should-i-go-back-to-school-for-graphic-design) or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/69738/what-career-paths-does-a-graphic-design-degree-offer or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55398/certificate-programs-vs-an-associates-degree or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/768/is-design-school-a-requirement-for-graphic-design - Reality is, there is no certificate, license or degree which is mandatory to work in the industry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which country you're from and what the local requirements are, but generally speaking you don't need a diploma of any kind to become a designer. People can get decent jobs with just their Behance portfolio and then, as you accumulate more experience you will improve your portfolio, get better jobs and nobody will even look at your diploma at some point.